# Decreasing runtime by using index variables in fortran/MPI

Tags: arrays, performance, fortran, mpi

I saw in some CFD code that they used index variables for accessing different array entries. Following is a short example:

```
integer :: i,j
integer :: im,ip
real,dimension(0:200,0:200) :: array

do i=1,199
   ip = i+1
   im = i-1
   do j=0:200
      var1(i) = 0.5 * ( array(ip,j) - array(i ,j) )
      var2(i) = 0.5 * ( array(i ,j) - array(im,j) )
   enddo
enddo
```

Is there any advantage with this? Regarding runtime is there a difference if I use `array(i+1,j)` instead of `array(ip,j)`?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure -- what have your measurements revealed ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I wont try it on the actual code because it is a bit longer :), therefore I thought i ask before changing everthing. I will try a dummy routine and see if there is an improvement!

Comment: I think this is only meant to make the code clearer to the user. Looking at the code's format (how everything is aligned), this might be the only objective

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically, you don't have to do the addition 200 times, but just once before the loop

```
  do j=0,200
```

In practice an optimizing compiler should be able to optimize such usage for you anyway.

Comment: Do you by any change know if the intel ifort does that? Or the gnu gfortran?

Comment: They are able to do much more, like vectorizing the loop. The final code will be much different and doesn't have to look like a loop. Try using `-fdump-tree-original` and `-fdump-tree-optimized` in gfortran yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that!